# SQLite3 table not accepting INSERT INTO statements. The table is created, and so is the database, but nothing is passed into it

Tags: php, database, sqlite

```
<?php
try
{
        //open the database
        $db = new PDO('sqlite:music.db');
        $db->exec("DELETE from Music;");
        $db->exec("INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Whatd I Say', 'Ray Charles', '1956');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Smells Like Teen Spirit.', 'Nirvana', '1991');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Hey Jude', 'The Beatles', '1968');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Johnny B. Goode', 'Chuck Berry', '1958');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Good Vibrations', 'The Beach Boys', '1966');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Respect', 'Aretha Franklin', '1967');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Whats Going On', 'Marvin Gaye', '1971');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Imagine', 'John Lennon', '1971');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('(I Cant Get No) Satisfaction', 'Rolling Stones', '1965');" .
                    "INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES ('Like A Rolling Stone', 'Bob Dylan', '1965');");


        //now output the data to a simple html table...
        //example of specifier  --> WHERE First=\'Josh\'; <--
        print "<table border=1>";
        print "<tr><td>Title</td><td>Author</td><td>Y.O.P.</td></tr>";
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Music ');
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            print "<td>".$row['Title']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$row['Author']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$row['ReleaseDate']."</td></tr>";
            }
        print "</table>";

        $db = NULL;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

---

I am not sure why nothing is being inserted into the table. The file 'music.db' exists in the right path.

For the record, I can only use SQlite3, no SQL allowed. PHP is allowed, so is SQLite3.

Comment: What specific error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the difference between these two lines?

```
"INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, Release Date) VALUES 
"INSERT INTO Music(Title, Author, ReleaseDate) VALUES 
                                         ^
```

There you go. Take that space out of the column name, and you should be fine.

---

This is the content of my music.db before running the code.

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE music (Title text, Author text, ReleaseDate text);
COMMIT;
```

The code you currently have posted in your question now runs successfully without modification here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that error, I feel silly for not finding it myself.

However, this did not fix the problem. Information is still not being added into the table itself.

Comment: That's the only change I had to make for it to work here. I'll look at it again later today.

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations of SQLite3 restrict each execute command to only one query. Example, you cannot chain the INSERT like you have done, but must call $db->exec() for each insert.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, as the '.' at the end of each line should combine the information, and I know this 'format' has worked before. I appreciate the feedback though.